# I can't move from an activity to another activity (from register once clicked to register form)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**Main activity.java**

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin, btnSignup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.btnUserLogin);
        btnSignup=findViewById(R.id.btnUserSignIn);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

            btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
         }
        }
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```java
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            View _mw = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            setContentView(_mw);
        }
    }
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```java
    public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        }
    }
```

No errors are raised it just displays runs successfully, the landing page appears where I have the login and register, but once I click on login or register buttons it does not move to the form that I need to fill.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the same view as the main activity in your login activity --

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*View _mw = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(_mw);*/
        setContentView(R.layout.your_login_activity_layout_here)
    }
}
```

So basically it's shows the same view again.